# Pyodbc execute two dependend procedures

Tags: python-3.x, pyodbc

i have two empty tables **A** and **B**, the **A** is fed by the procedure at the step 1, the **B** table is fed at the step 2 based on table **A** data. My issue is that after the execution of the program **A** contains data and not **B**.
I tried to execute the step 2 separately (not the same program) and it works fine.

```
import pyodbc
database = 'database '
driver= '{SQL Server}'
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER='+driver+';SERVER='+server+';PORT=1433;DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute('''EXEC [dbo].[LoadDataTableA]''') #Step 1
cursor.execute('''EXEC [dbo].[LoadDataTableB]''') #Step 2
cnxn.commit()
cnxn.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `NO COUNT ON` for your stored procedure or pyodbc thinks that any output from the procedure is the end of the procedure and will move on to the next `execute`. With `NOCOUNT ON` it will wait for the procedure to finish. Also check that the stored procedure has no `PRINT` statements or `RAISEERROR` as those will trigger ending the `execute` as well.

```py
import pyodbc
database = 'database '
driver= '{SQL Server}'
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER='+driver+';SERVER='+server+';PORT=1433;DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute('''SET NO COUNT ON; EXEC [dbo].[LoadDataTableA]''') #Step 1
cursor.execute('''SET NO COUNT ON; EXEC [dbo].[LoadDataTableB]''') #Step 2
cnxn.commit()
cnxn.close()
```

Comment: i tried that but still having the problem. do i need to add Sleep() ?

Comment: Actually i have a print inside the sp, and i have set the NO COUNT ON inside each sp. is that correct?

Comment: @MaherKebaier No `NO COUNT ON` only affects the "(n) rows affected" statement. You will need to remove the print statement from the stored procedure as well because `pyodbc` will think those mean the procedure is done as well